# Custom Android Spinner doesn't show text completely

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have a created a custom `ArrayAdapter` to hold a tuple. I use one of the items in the tuple as the text to be displayed on a spinner which I have placed on a page.
Here is the code for my `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class SpinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ObjectsForSpinner> {
    private ArrayList<ObjectsForSpinner> _values;
    public ObjectsForSpinner getItem(int position)
    {
        return _values.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
         TextView label = new TextView(context);
         label.settextColor(Color.BLACK);
         label.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
         label.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         label.setText(_values.get(position).getSpinnerStr());
         return label;
    }
}
```

`_values.get(position).getSpinnerStr()` is where I return the text. The return type is `String`. The problem is the text is not displayed completely. When I return `Sales Department` it only shows `Sales` without `Department`.

I even tried `label.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);` but no luck yet. Would some one please tell me how to go around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this problem before. The problem is that the `TextView` inside your Spinner completely ignores the parts after the space character when the `TextView` size is smaller than the whole String. You could identify this by removing the space characters from your `String` and displaying it. It will show you the part of the text that could fit inside your `TextView`. But the moment the spaces are back, they are all gone.

Answer (score 0):

Set something like this :

```
label.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
label.setSingleLine(true);
```